# open another browser in spite of default browser

Tags: android

hiii..i m developing an app in which as user click on a link it should prompt the user to open link in myAppbrowser (which i will create) or default browser(like activity chooser do).
as user click on default browser app prompt again that, 'this page cant open in default browser'.
after that the browser which i make should run...

how to implement this....plz help me

Comment: Just as a good tip: If you never accept any anwsers or vote up anwsers, people won't likely to anwser your questsions at all, as it's not very nice to be so selfish and not thank others for their anwsers to your questions. You've posted 13 questions, and you haven't voted up a single one or even accepted it. So most people wouldn't even take the time to post an anwser ^^

Comment: hii sir thanks for your tip. but i actually dont know how to accept ans.or vote up them. i see all the answers which u all send me. but i dont know how to mark them accepted.

Comment: There's a tick mark around voting area of every Answer. you can click a tick mark against the answer which you want to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Depends.

If the user clicks on your link, from one of the browsers (which aren't made by yourself), then no: It's not possible for security reasons. Android is designd to have the user choose which app he want's to use to open a certain Link (better term would be: Intent).

If the user clicks on a link in a WebView you created, then it may be possible to intercept that link and create a custom selection screen (or directly send it to your App without asking for a choice). I've forgot which method of WebView you need to override to intercept link clicks, have seen it somewhere here on Stackoverflow, just don't have the link atm.

Comment: its onPageStarted() to know which URL WebView is going to load.